# Https problem with channel form

Tags: assets, safecracker, wygwam, ssl

I have a problem with a channel form working over https.My form allows users edit their profiles for a staff directory and has a lot of fields including some assets , wygwam and matrix fields.When i go to the page over https all of those fields aren't working and i get errors like

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://mysite/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
```

Blocked loading mixed active content "http://mysite/themes/third_party/assets/scripts/matrix.min.js?2.5"

So the obvious problem is that these fields are requesting files over http rather than https but im not sure why this is happening.

I have setup my site to convert relative paths in my config

```
  $protocol                          = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&     $_SERVER['HTTP'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
  $base_url                          = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $base_path                         = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  $system_folder                     = APPPATH . '../';
  $images_folder                     = 'images';
  $images_path                       = $base_path . '/' . $images_folder;
  $images_url                        = $base_url . '/' . $images_folder;

  $env_config['index_page']          = '';
  $env_config['site_index']          = '';
  $env_config['base_url']            = $base_url . '/';
  $env_config['site_url']            = $env_config['base_url'];
  $env_config['cp_url']              = $env_config['base_url'] . 
'admin/index.php';
 $env_config['theme_folder_path']   = $base_path   . '/themes/';
 $env_config['theme_folder_url']    = $base_url    . '/themes/';
 $env_config['third_party_path']    = $base_path   '/admin/expressionengine/third_party/';
```

I have also set secure_return="yes"  and secure_action="yes" in my form header so im not sure where I am going wrong

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have decided to set https as my default  protocol
So i changed this

```
 $protocol= (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&     $_SERVER['HTTP'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
```

to this

```
 $protocol=  'https://';
```

This has sorted my issues and I hope to move the whole site to https soon

Comment: Man from the future here... 2023 to be exact. Thanks, this really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your CP and themes folder are not set to run https.

Make sure your cp url and themes folder are set to run https://

You'll possibly run into the same thing with any "ACT=" urls if the protocols don't match.